# Performance issues while AWS Glue Spark Bucketing for large table

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I have one large dimension which is used across many tables. The datasets has 300 gb parquet compressed format. I am building bucketed table to get get rid of mane exchange in down stream jobs.

While writing the bucketed table, it's taking a lot of time.
Here is code below and some snapshot from UI. Please let me know what can I modify.

1. I need 320 buckets here
2. Used repartition
3. Why in one exchange number of partition is 1. highlighted in black

   df=spark.sql(f''' select as12,snap_day
   from al.as12dim
   ad where snap_day=cast("{snap_date}" as date) and region_id={region_id} limit 80000 ''')
   df.repartition(320,expr("pmod(hash(as12), 320)")).write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('region_id','snap_day').bucketBy(320,'as12').option("path", path).saveAsTable(as12_tbl_name)

[image]